# linux + how to verify user is in group?

Tags: linux, rhel, users, group, usermod

how to verify that new user was added to group?

example

by this syntax I will add the user dog to group - white_house_group

```
usermod -a -G white_house_group dog
```

after that , how to verify that user dog is really in white_house_group group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `usermod -a -G` command will add the given user to a supplementary group.  The change will be reflected for the user the next time that user logs in.

The user will see the new group in the output of the `groups` command, and in `id -nG`. Any other user may use `id -nG dog`.

The username of the user will additionally be listed in the group's entry in `/etc/group` and/or in the output of `getent group` (also `getent group white_house_group` to only see that one group).

---

As a programmatic example:

```
usermod -a -G white_house_group dog
if id -nG dog | ! grep -q white_house_group; then
   echo 'user not added to group!' >&2
   exit 1
fi
```

... but one may argue that `usermod` should exit with a failure if the modification was unsuccessful:

```
if ! usermod -a -G ...; then
    echo error >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

However, I don't have a Linux system to test this on.

Comment: so just to summary - I need to do   id -nG dof | grep white_house_group

Comment: @jango Something like that, yes. I've added another example in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command:

```
id <username>
```

and so

```
id dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use below command

```
groups dog
```

It will show for which all the groups user dog  belongs to